# npm install error ssh

Tags: git, npm, ssh, proxy

I downloaded a release of maputnik from https://github.com/maputnik/editor/releases/tag/v1.2.0 and try to install with npm on windows 7 behind a corporate proxy with ssh lock.

I get the following error:

```
    $ npm install
    npm ERR! Error while executing:
    npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/josdejong/jsonlint.git
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
    npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

After reading several posts concerning npm install behind proxy, I changed my npm and git configuration:
npm (.npmrc file):

```
    strict-ssl=false
    proxy=http://user:password@proxy.company.com:8080
    https-proxy=http://user:password@proxy.company.com:8080
    registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

git (.gitconfig file):

```
    [http]
        proxy = http://user:password@proxy.company.com:8080
        sslverify = false
    [https]
        proxy = http://user:password@proxy.company.com:8080
        sslverify = false
    [url "https://github.com/"]
        insteadOf = ssh://git@github.com/
    [url "https://"]
        insteadOf = git://
```

Now at least `git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/josdejong/jsonlint.git` 
 and `git clone ssh://git@github.com/josdejong/jsonlint.git` work. But I still get the same error with `npm install`.

Seems that the configuration works for git but not for npm. Is there any other place where I must configure proxy or url substitution?